# ClickableSpan not... Clicking

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

If I have a ClickableSpan in a TextView, which works fine when it's LinearLayout in a ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        ...
        ...
        <TextView w/ ClickableSpan />
        ...
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

why would the ClickableSpan not work in the same configuration as the above, but inside of a TableLayout and TableRow:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        ...
        ...
        <TableLayout>
            ...
            ...
                <TableRow>
                    ...
                    ...
                    <TextView w/ ClickableSpan />
                    ...
                    ...
                </TableRow>
            ...
            ...
        </TableLayout>
        ...
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @Nicholas have you looked to see the the above link answers your question. The questions situations seem slightly different. This question already has many close votes so you should act fast. If it doesnt answer your question please share the details by editing your question.